Showing a list of posts in Flutter
I have a social media app which like any other social media apps shows a list of posts which is vertically scrollable. So the problem is that it the functionality isn't working as expected and I don't know what's wrong. I'm sure there are posts available to show but the problem might be the UI. This is what I have done to fetch posts from Firebase:
 final postsProvider = FutureProvider.family<List<Post>, model.User>(
      (ref, model.User user) async {
    final friends = user.following;

    final allPosts = await Future.wait(
      friends.map((frId) async {
        final asyncValue = ref.read(postPoolProvider(frId));
        return asyncValue.maybeWhen(
          data: (posts) => posts,
          orElse: () => <Post>[],
        );
      }),
    );

    return allPosts.expand((posts) => posts).toList();
  });


So basically here I'm creating a FutureProvider which takes in two arguments, ref and model.User user and returns a list of posts. The postPoolProvider is used to get a list of all the post of the user who's userId corresponds to frId. Here's how I used this in building the UI:
Widget _buildPosts(BuildContext context, model.User user) {
    final hiddenPosts = ref.watch(hiddenPostsProvider);
    final postAsyncValue = ref.watch(postsProvider(user));

    return postAsyncValue.when(
      data: (data) {
        final visiblePosts =
            data.where((post) => !hiddenPosts.contains(post.id)).toList();

        return CustomScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          slivers: [
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) {
                  if (index != 0 && index % 4 == 0) {
                    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6;
                    return _ad != null
                        ? SizedBox(height: height, child: AdWidget(ad: _ad!))
                        : const SizedBox.shrink();
                  } else {
                    final postIndex = index - (index ~/ 4);

                    if (postIndex < visiblePosts.length) {
                      return PostCard(
                          id: visiblePosts[postIndex].userId,
                          user: user,
                          index: postIndex);
                    } else {
                      return const SizedBox.shrink();
                    }
                  }
                },
                childCount: visiblePosts.length + (visiblePosts.length ~/ 3),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
      error: (error, stack) => _buildErrorScreen(error),
      loading: () => _buildLoadingScreen(),
    );
  }


I called the above widget as a body of a NestedScrollView. I'm 100% certain there are posts in my database so the problem is either with home I'm fetching them or building the UI. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

I think you should use a listener provider, something like this:
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

part '....';

@riverpod
class Posts extends _$Posts {
  @override
  Future<List<Post>> build(model.User user) => fetch();

  Future<List<Post>> fetch() async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    final friends = user.following; //note that user is visible everywhere in the class
    final allPosts = List.empty(growable: true);
    for (final frId in friends) {
      final posts = await ref.read(postPoolProvider(frId).future);
      allPosts.add(posts);
    }
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() => allPosts);

    return allPosts;
  }
}

then in your Widget , where you wrote:
 final postAsyncValue = ref.watch(postsProvider(user));

you should use these lines of code :
 @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
      final postAsyncValue = ref.watch(postsProvider(user));
     return switch (postAsyncValue ) {
       AsyncError<List<Post>>(:final error) => _buildErrorScreen(error),
         ),
       AsyncData<List<Post>>(:final value) => _buildWithData(context, ref,  value),
       _ =>  _buildLoadingScreen(),
     };
   }
 

in the _buildWithData(...) you should put your _buildPosts(...) code, but simpler, look that the logic loading-error-load_data is already written in this  build() method.
